# Cloning element only once and removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have set up the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/48/) to demonstrate what I am doing.  As you can see, I have various inputs.  Each input has a checkbox to add an additional row.  If a checkbox is checked, it should add a new input underneath the checked input.

Now what I have seems to do that without any problems - although it could probably be improved.

At the moment I am having issues with

```
$(this).closest(".labelAndInput").remove();
```

So each section (I have given them different background colours to show the sections) should only be allowed to have one additional input.  At the moment, if I check the box, uncheck it, then check it again, it adds a third input.

The above problem can probably be solved with the following.  If a checkbox is unchecked, it should remove the cloned div.  This is where I am having issues at the moment.  How can I remove the clone if the checkbox is unchecked?  It should remove the div it is related too, and not a random clone.

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The code for your question goes **in** your question, not just linked. Put the code in the question, ideally in the form of a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give your clone a class to identify it exactly. **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/50/)**

```
 $(function() {
   $('input:checkbox[name="labelNewline"]').change(function() {
     if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        var clone = $(this).parent().siblings(".labelAndInput").first().clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
        clone.addClass('clone');
     } else {
         $(this).parent().siblings(".clone").remove();
     }
   });
 });
```